# Grails GSP Organization

Tags: grails, gsp

I am looking for a best practise on how to organise grails GSP, and also on how to manage GSP extensions.  I am working on an application where I need to create my own GSP HTML elements as well as override standard GSP elements and I would like to know how to organise them.

My consideration is to write a Grails Plugin which has its own Taglib with my own namespace. And creating all the elements that I need and also override the existing ones.

Are there any good examples out there on how to organise things like that?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that taglibs is the best place for GSP customizations. Even the [Grails Website](https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website/) have their own tags. Some points that I can remember now:

- There's [this great post](http://www.viaboxxsystems.de/mastering-grails-taglibs) that give you some tips about taglibs. The post shows you how to test, overwrite and reuse tags.
- For namespaces, I recommend you check first which plugins the app will use, to avoid conflicts.
- For integration tests you can extend `GroovyPagesTestCase`
- Generating html inside a taglib can become a little hard to maintain, but you can create templates and use [g.render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html) (if is inside a plugin, always define this attribute in the call) or use [GSP Taglibs plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-taglib)